# Plperlu func with column as param

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, perl

I have postgres 9.5, and want to use plperlu as lang to get result from curl put

My func is:

```
create or replace function langDetect(str text) returns text as $$
use warnings;
use strict;
my $str = $_[0];
my $output = `curl -X PUT --data $str http://localhost:9998/language/string`;
return($output);
$$ language plperlu;
```

When i use:

```
select langDetect('some text');
```

Everything is ok

But:

```
Select langDetect(column) from table limit 1;
```

Returns empty string.
Column type is text.

Any help will be good!

Comment: Since the web server seems to run on a machine you access to, hove a look in the logs what actually gets called and check if that is right.

Comment: @stickybit its running and it seems that it puts empty string on input of function

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: We need the value of column that works when manually supplied, and but not when read from a table. Perhaps you're reading in `NULL`? Consider making your function `STRICT`, and running it with `set client_min_messages = DEBUG1` and running the SELECT with the function call.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I explained, that if i manually type text into function param, it works, but if text from column from table it seems than nothing goes to http server

Comment: Well, I don't believe you.. So prove it. ;) Give me a test that fails. You have a car that doesn't start. I have one that does start. You gotta tell me why our cars are different or there is nothing we can do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me.  I'm guessing that curl just returns the empty string for the specific input you are using.

```
create or replace function langDetect(str text) returns text as $$   
use warnings;
use strict;
my $str = $_[0];
my $output = `echo $str`;
return($output);
$$ language plperlu;

select langDetect('some data');
 langdetect 
------------
 some data +

create table baz as select 'hi'::text as col;
select langDetect(col) from baz;
 langdetect 
------------
 hi        +
```

I hope you really trust everyone with access to this function, because they can find an input that will really ruin your day.

Answer (score -1):

I believe I've found my problem.

My column includes special symbols; they seem to be what caused my functionn to get empty results.

Comment: the best fix it to correct langDetect() so that it can handle special characters correctly.